# Move CComBSTR to std::vector?

Tags: c++11, atl

Is there a way to move CComBSTR object to std::vector without copying the underlying string? It seems the following code doesn't work.

```
CComBSTR str(L"SomeStr");
std::vector<CComBSTR> vStr;

vStr.push_back((CComBSTR)str.Detach());
```

Comment: re "(CComBSTR)" cast. Never cast in ignorance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done some experiment and seems the latest CComBSTR supports move semantics so it can be written as:

```
CComBSTR str(L"SomeStr");
std::vector<CComBSTR> vStr;

vStr.push_back(std::move(str));
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't work because `Detach` gives you a `BSTR`, not a `CComBSTR`. You could have used `std::vector<BSTR> vStr`, as long as you realise that `BSTR` points to the first character of the string, but there's also a length prefix before the memory it points to (see, e.g. [BSTR (Automation)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221069%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)), so you'd need to be careful with managing it.

Alternatively, you could have used

```
CComBSTR str(L"SomeStr");
std::vector<CComBSTR> vStr;

vStr.push_back(str);
```

which would make a copy of the string.

The MSDN page on [CComBSTR](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zh7x9w3f.aspx) does not indicate it has any move-semantics, but it might have been added to the code without the documentation being updated.
I don't think so though, in which case your `std::move` solution in your answer will be the same as my second example: a simple copy.

Comment: I checked that there is move constructor in my `class CComBSTR`, so it is expected to do move operation. I have to check whether it real happens.

Comment: If it's there you can expect it to work and you can use that.